# Unable to assign "form" attribute to "input" tag via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

According to specification `input` tag has a `form` attribute, which Specifies the form the `input` element belongs to.

HTML example:

```
<form id="putForm" action="index.html" method="post"></form>
<input type="text" id="field" value="foo">
```

Javascript code:

```
const putForm = document.querySelector('#putForm');
const field = document.querySelector('#field');

field.form = "putForm";
```

Attribute is not assigned, shows "null" when inspected with dev tools.

Comment: why not put the `input` inside the `form`?

Comment: In my app I tried to put the form with `input` inside a `td` table cell but apparently it won't work correctly.

Comment: did you try `field.setAttribute('form', 'putForm');`

Comment: Where did you learn that input has a form attribute? In my experience, I've never come across this attribute. And anyways, what are you trying to accomplish with the 'form' attribute?

Comment: @jeninja - [MDN input attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#form).

Comment: It worked. Even though attributes like `type`, `name` and `value` can all be edited a "simple" way without problem.

Comment: @IgorCheglakov - those are properties, form is an attribute.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. — The relationship between the `value` attribute and the `value` property is … complicated. It isn't as simple as you might think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with the following code:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('field');
input.attributes.form.value = "putForm";
```

Answer (score 2):

The `form` property has, for a very long time, been a read-only reference for the form element associated with the `input` and *not* a string with the ID of the form in it.

When the `form` attribute was introduced, the `form` property was already taken.

Use the `setAttribute` method instead.

```
field.setAttribute("form", "putForm");
```

Answer (score -2):

why don't you just do

$("#field").val('anything');

and you are done

Comment: why do you assume op is using jquery?

Comment: even if he was, this does not answer the question.

Comment: The question isn't asking how to set the value of the input, so they aren't doing this because the result would be nothing like what they are trying to do.

Comment: if not jquery then just do document.getElementById('id').value='anything'

Comment: @ammarjaved — Again: **not** what the OP is trying to acheive